# Unexpected SQLite size

Tags: database, sqlite, sql

I was testing how the following schemas compare against one another in SQLite (space and queries/s).

My original schema uses a `0` or `1` value for each `bit_*` field:

```
CREATE TABLE "original"
(
    "id"        TEXT NOT NULL,
    "bit_a"     INTEGER(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "bit_b"     INTEGER(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "bit_c"     INTEGER(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

My alternative schema uses a bit mask instead with values ranging from `0` to `7`:

```
CREATE TABLE "alternative"
(
    "id"        TEXT NOT NULL,
    "bit_mask"  INTEGER(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

According to the [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#storageclasses):

> **INTEGER**
>
> Signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.

I would expect each row in the `original` table to take 2 more bytes than the `alternative` table. However, after inserting the exact same data in two different database files I discover that the `alternative` version is actually **5.5% bigger** than the `original` version.

Anyone knows the reason why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the SQLite File Format documentation, section 2.1. https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html

Integer values 0 and 1 are special cases which take less disk space than other values.